# replace word preserving the original space

Tags: javascript

What span should I use in order to preserve the original space of the word that is been replaced with underscore.

```html
<p id="myID">this is a sunny day<p>
```

```js
var Phrase = document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML;
Replace = Phrase.replace("sunny", '<span class="selected">' + "_" + '</span>');
document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML = Replace;
```

```css
span.selected {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the result you're after? It's not clear if you want something like `this is a _     day` or `this is a _____ day`

Comment: And be more specific about the spacing issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean this option "this is a _____ day"

Comment: Use the `length` of the string you want to replace to create the same number of  `_`

Comment: @charlietfl that won't work for any font other than monospace.

Comment: Thank you all for the ideas !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider wrapping your word in a `<span>` element:

```js
Replace = Phrase.replace(/sunny/g, '<span class="selected">$&</span>');
```

Then, you could make the text transparent and giving it `text-decoration` with color:

```css
.selected {
    background-color: #000;
    color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline #fff;
}
```

That way, you preserve the original width of the word and also word wrapping.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you're after though, because if that's a quiz or something, you may want to keep the word out of the DOM.

Comment: Updated to make it white on black.

Comment: I had no idea you could colour the underline in CSS. Very nice!

Comment: Yeah, I found it myself a bit ago and I was surprised as well!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this answer be useful

```js
var Phrase = document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML;
var word ='sunny';
  
   Replace = Phrase.replace(word, `<span class="selected">${'_'.repeat(word.length)}</span>`);
document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML = Replace;
```

```css
span.selected {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<p id="myID">this is a sunny day<p>
```

Comment: You can use `var dash = '_'.repeat(word.length);` saves you the for loop :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be replaced by several underscores. you can do this

```
Replace = Phrase.replace("sunny", '<span class="selected">' + "sunny".split("").map(function(e){ return "_" }).join("") + '</span>');
```

The above function will create underscores according to the size of the string used.